# Does ghost script takes some time to copy converted file in given location

Tags: php, linux, pdf, ghostscript

I am using ghost script to convert version of file as below.

```
shell_exec( 'gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=' . $strTempConvertedPdfFilePath . ' ' . $strTempFilePath );
```

(I am assuming that above command is synchronous and next line executes only after completing ghost script execution.)

Just afert this I am using $strTempConvertedPdfFilePath location if converted file exists at path.

It sometimes works and returns true and sometimes not and return false for same file and path by just refreshing the page.

I suspect ghost script takes some time to copy converted file in given location and due to which the file_exists return true/false intermittently.

Please let me know if anyone have faced similar issue and have solution to it.

Answer (score 0):

Ghostscript (or more specifically the pdfwrite device) does not take any time to 'copy' the file, because it doesn't copy the file.

The final destination file (`-sOutputFile`) is opened, the contents written and the file closed before the device is unloaded and Ghostscript exits and returns control to the shell.

I'm no expert on shell programming or PHP, but I would be inclined to think that the shell_exec returns control to the program before the child process exits. Alternatively it takes the operating system some time to detect the existence or validity of the destination file. The obvious solution is to stick a small delay in before testing the file.

Comment: Thank you Ken for clarifying file write process. I was also thinking about adding a delay. but was not sure about how much would be enough as I was thinking it is output file write time,  which can vary depending on file size.  now if ur's is the case then it would take almost same time always.